# Linq Take not working

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I'm using Linq and MySql database. I'm trying to take just the first 10 results from a list, but Linq's Take does not filter the results, it just returns all 59 of them.

This is the code:

```
 List<EComQuoteSearchModel> results = new List<EComQuoteSearchModel>();

        //do not included quotes marked as deleted in the search results
       // int deletedStatusId = (int)IMSourcingPortal.Services.ecomQuoteSystem.EComQuoteStatus.Deleted;
        //&& qo.nquote_status.StatusId != deletedStatusId

        results = (from qo in db.nquote_orderheaders
                   join st in db.nquote_status on qo.StatusId equals st.StatusId
                   where (qo.QuoteOrderNumber.Contains(term) 
                        || qo.nquote_status.Name.Contains(term)
                        || qo.CustomerName.Contains(term)
                        || qo.IMCustomerNumber.Contains(term)) 
                   select new EComQuoteSearchModel()
                   {
                       CustomerName = qo.CustomerName,
                       CustomerNo = qo.IMCustomerNumber,
                       QuoteNo = qo.QuoteOrderNumber,
                       Status = st.Name
                   }).ToList();

        IEnumerable<EComQuoteSearchModel> firstTen = results.Take(10);
        var toret = firstTen.ToList();
        return toret;
```

Any idea appreciated.

Comment: Use Take() before ToList()

Comment: Please show the code where you are proving to yourself that it prints out 59 of them.  (also, you should not use `.ToList` before calling `Take` as that will force you to always download all the rows from the database instead of having the backend do that work)

Comment: @MikeSW, I tried using Take() before ToList(), but the result is the same.

Comment: Please edit your post to show us the modified code. Also, try to use Take() before Selecting, it might do the trick

Comment: @MikeSW, it would not "do the trick".  Your suggestion could not possibly have any bearing on why `firstTen` allegedly contains more than 10 elements.

Comment: @KirkWoll I don't know if the MySql Linq provider takes into consideration the Take() after select. It's all about SQl generation, it would be useful if the OP could post the generated sql.

Comment: @MikeSW, the LINQ provider cannot have anything to do with the problem since he invoked `Take` on a simple `List<T>` (`results`).

Comment: @KirkWoll Read the first comments. Take() invoked **before** ToList() but after Select() didn't work.

Comment: @MikeSW, I'm *just looking at the code*.  Do you notice how `.Take` is being invoked against a `List<T>`?  SQL generation becomes 100% moot because of that.

Comment: @OctavianEpure , what is revealed in the debugging. have you checked the contents of 'toret' just  before return?

Comment: @KirkWoll Are you trolling? Can't you see my first comment and then the OP comment?

Comment: The return value toret should have the 10 items and the results should have 59 items. There is no dependancy to mysql after materializing the query with ToList(). results.Take(10) should return 10 results in anycase if there is db included or not. I'm guessing theproblem is because the actual query sent does not limit the results...

Answer (score 1):

After you materialize the results with .ToList() its absolutely same situation. If you want filter only the first 10 results from database WITH THE QUERY. You need to include the .Take(10) before materializing the query.

Below code will write 5 lines to console.

```
// This simulates the results from your query after you materialize it with Tolist()
var results = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };
foreach(var str in results.Take(5))
{
    Console.WriteLine(str); 
}
```

Is the problem because your query sent to mysql database does not filter it?